# How to compute the $(2n-1)$th complex roots of 1?

Tags: analysis

I have to solve
$$
(e^{i\theta})^{2n-1}=1,
$$
i.e. to find the $(2n-1)$th roots on the unit circle.

How can I solve this?

---

I've read that I can use Euler's formula to write the solutions as
$$
e^{2\pi i\frac{k}{(2n-1)}}, ~~0\leq k< n.
$$
How do I get there?

Comment: Sorry, do not get there. With Dem-Moivre I only see that $e^{2\pi i/n}$ is a solution.

Comment: De Moivre, not Dem-Moivre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $z=re^{i\theta}$ such that $z^{2n-1} = 1$. In other words: $$(re^{i\theta})^{2n-1} = e^{0} \implies r^{2n-1}e^{(2n-1)i\theta} = 1\cdot e^0$$ From here $r=1$, since $r>0$. And the exponential has period $2\pi i $, so: $$(2n-1)i\theta = 0 + 2k\pi i, \quad k \in \Bbb Z \implies \theta = \frac{2k\pi}{2n-1},\quad k\in \Bbb Z. $$ Values of $k$ from $0$ to $2n-2$ will give you different roots. You'll get the same roots again for $k \geq 2n-1$.

Comment: How do I see that for $k\geq 2n-1$ I get the same roots again?

Comment: Because the equation $z^{2n-1} -1 = 0 $ has $2n-1$ solutions and for $k$ ranging to $0$ from $2n-2$ we already got $2n-1$ roots. We can't get new things after that. Maybe you should pick a particular case, say, $n=2$ to make things easier and do the calculations, to feel it

Answer (score 1):

One way to understand Euler's solution is by looking at the unit circle:

Multiplying a complex number with $e^{i\theta}$ is essentially rotating it in $\theta$ radians

if we define `g` as:

$g\equiv e^{\frac{i2\pi}{(2n-1)}}$

`g` is equivalent to a rotation of $\frac{360}{2n-1}$ degrees

Your question could be reformulated as:

I am going to make `2n-1` turns of angle $\theta$, and I want to be facing the same orientation as I started, what turn should I make ?

The answer is $\theta\in\{\frac{2\pi}{2n-1},\frac{4\pi}{2n-1},\dots,\frac{(2n-2)2\pi}{2n-1},2\pi\}$

Which is equivalent to $\{g^0,g^1,\dots,g^{2n-2},g^{2n-1}\}$